# Cannot deploy laravel application to Heroku ( build log given below ) Please healp?

Tags: php, laravel, nginx, heroku

-----> Building on the Heroku-20 stack

-----> Using buildpack: heroku/php

-----> PHP app detected

-----> Bootstrapping...

-----> Installing platform packages...

```
   - php (8.1.1)

   - ext-mbstring (bundled with php)

   - composer (2.2.3)

   - apache (2.4.51)

   - nginx (1.20.2)
```

-----> Installing dependencies...

```
   Composer version 2.2.3 2021-12-31 12:18:53

   Installing dependencies from lock file

   Verifying lock file contents can be installed on current platform.

   Package operations: 64 installs, 0 updates, 0 removals

     - Downloading doctrine/inflector (2.0.4)

     - Downloading doctrine/lexer (1.2.1)

     - Downloading dragonmantank/cron-expression (v2.3.1)

     - Downloading voku/portable-ascii (1.5.6)

     - Downloading symfony/polyfill-ctype (v1.23.0)

     - Downloading phpoption/phpoption (1.8.1)

     - Downloading vlucas/phpdotenv (v4.2.2)

     - Downloading symfony/css-selector (v6.0.2)

     - Downloading tijsverkoyen/css-to-inline-styles (2.2.4)

     - Downloading symfony/polyfill-php80 (v1.23.1)

     - Downloading symfony/polyfill-mbstring (v1.23.1)

     - Downloading symfony/var-dumper (v5.4.2)

     - Downloading symfony/deprecation-contracts (v3.0.0)

     - Downloading symfony/routing (v5.4.0)

     - Downloading symfony/process (v5.4.2)

     - Downloading symfony/polyfill-php73 (v1.23.0)

     - Downloading symfony/polyfill-php72 (v1.23.0)

     - Downloading symfony/polyfill-intl-normalizer (v1.23.0)

     - Downloading symfony/polyfill-intl-idn (v1.23.0)

     - Downloading symfony/mime (v5.4.2)

     - Downloading symfony/http-foundation (v5.4.2)

     - Downloading psr/event-dispatcher (1.0.0)

     - Downloading symfony/event-dispatcher-contracts (v3.0.0)

     - Downloading symfony/event-dispatcher (v6.0.2)

     - Downloading psr/log (2.0.0)

     - Downloading symfony/error-handler (v5.4.2)

     - Downloading symfony/http-kernel (v5.4.2)

     - Downloading symfony/finder (v5.4.2)

     - Downloading symfony/polyfill-intl-grapheme (v1.23.1)

     - Downloading symfony/string (v6.0.2)

     - Downloading psr/container (1.1.2)

     - Downloading symfony/service-contracts (v2.4.1)

     - Downloading symfony/console (v5.4.2)

     - Downloading symfony/polyfill-iconv (v1.23.0)

     - Downloading egulias/email-validator (2.1.25)

     - Downloading swiftmailer/swiftmailer (v6.3.0)

     - Downloading symfony/polyfill-php81 (v1.23.0)

     - Downloading ramsey/collection (1.2.2)

     - Downloading brick/math (0.9.3)

     - Downloading ramsey/uuid (4.2.3)

     - Downloading psr/simple-cache (1.0.1)

     - Downloading opis/closure (3.6.2)

     - Downloading symfony/translation-contracts (v3.0.0)

     - Downloading symfony/translation (v6.0.2)

     - Downloading nesbot/carbon (2.55.2)

     - Downloading monolog/monolog (2.3.5)

     - Downloading league/mime-type-detection (1.9.0)

     - Downloading league/flysystem (1.1.9)

     - Downloading league/commonmark (1.6.6)

     - Downloading laravel/framework (v7.30.6)

     - Downloading fideloper/proxy (4.4.1)

     - Downloading asm89/stack-cors (v2.0.5)

     - Downloading fruitcake/laravel-cors (v2.0.5)

     - Downloading psr/http-message (1.0.1)

     - Downloading psr/http-client (1.0.1)

     - Downloading ralouphie/getallheaders (3.0.3)

     - Downloading psr/http-factory (1.0.1)

     - Downloading guzzlehttp/psr7 (2.1.0)

     - Downloading guzzlehttp/promises (1.5.1)

     - Downloading guzzlehttp/guzzle (7.4.1)

     - Downloading nikic/php-parser (v4.13.2)

     - Downloading psy/psysh (v0.10.12)

     - Downloading laravel/tinker (v2.6.3)

     - Downloading sheetdb/sheetdb-php (1.0.3)

     - Installing doctrine/inflector (2.0.4): Extracting archive

     - Installing doctrine/lexer (1.2.1): Extracting archive

     - Installing dragonmantank/cron-expression (v2.3.1): Extracting archive

     - Installing voku/portable-ascii (1.5.6): Extracting archive

     - Installing symfony/polyfill-ctype (v1.23.0): Extracting archive

     - Installing phpoption/phpoption (1.8.1): Extracting archive

     - Installing vlucas/phpdotenv (v4.2.2): Extracting archive

     - Installing symfony/css-selector (v6.0.2): Extracting archive

     - Installing tijsverkoyen/css-to-inline-styles (2.2.4): Extracting archive

     - Installing symfony/polyfill-php80 (v1.23.1): Extracting archive

     - Installing symfony/polyfill-mbstring (v1.23.1): Extracting archive

     - Installing symfony/var-dumper (v5.4.2): Extracting archive

     - Installing symfony/deprecation-contracts (v3.0.0): Extracting archive

     - Installing symfony/routing (v5.4.0): Extracting archive

     - Installing symfony/process (v5.4.2): Extracting archive

     - Installing symfony/polyfill-php73 (v1.23.0): Extracting archive

     - Installing symfony/polyfill-php72 (v1.23.0): Extracting archive

     - Installing symfony/polyfill-intl-normalizer (v1.23.0): Extracting archive

     - Installing symfony/polyfill-intl-idn (v1.23.0): Extracting archive

     - Installing symfony/mime (v5.4.2): Extracting archive

     - Installing symfony/http-foundation (v5.4.2): Extracting archive

     - Installing psr/event-dispatcher (1.0.0): Extracting archive

     - Installing symfony/event-dispatcher-contracts (v3.0.0): Extracting archive

     - Installing symfony/event-dispatcher (v6.0.2): Extracting archive

     - Installing psr/log (2.0.0): Extracting archive

     - Installing symfony/error-handler (v5.4.2): Extracting archive

     - Installing symfony/http-kernel (v5.4.2): Extracting archive

     - Installing symfony/finder (v5.4.2): Extracting archive

     - Installing symfony/polyfill-intl-grapheme (v1.23.1): Extracting archive

     - Installing symfony/string (v6.0.2): Extracting archive

     - Installing psr/container (1.1.2): Extracting archive

     - Installing symfony/service-contracts (v2.4.1): Extracting archive

     - Installing symfony/console (v5.4.2): Extracting archive

     - Installing symfony/polyfill-iconv (v1.23.0): Extracting archive

     - Installing egulias/email-validator (2.1.25): Extracting archive

     - Installing swiftmailer/swiftmailer (v6.3.0): Extracting archive

     - Installing symfony/polyfill-php81 (v1.23.0): Extracting archive

     - Installing ramsey/collection (1.2.2): Extracting archive

     - Installing brick/math (0.9.3): Extracting archive

     - Installing ramsey/uuid (4.2.3): Extracting archive

     - Installing psr/simple-cache (1.0.1): Extracting archive

     - Installing opis/closure (3.6.2): Extracting archive

     - Installing symfony/translation-contracts (v3.0.0): Extracting archive

     - Installing symfony/translation (v6.0.2): Extracting archive

     - Installing nesbot/carbon (2.55.2): Extracting archive

     - Installing monolog/monolog (2.3.5): Extracting archive

     - Installing league/mime-type-detection (1.9.0): Extracting archive

     - Installing league/flysystem (1.1.9): Extracting archive

     - Installing league/commonmark (1.6.6): Extracting archive

     - Installing laravel/framework (v7.30.6): Extracting archive

     - Installing fideloper/proxy (4.4.1): Extracting archive

     - Installing asm89/stack-cors (v2.0.5): Extracting archive

     - Installing fruitcake/laravel-cors (v2.0.5): Extracting archive

     - Installing psr/http-message (1.0.1): Extracting archive

     - Installing psr/http-client (1.0.1): Extracting archive

     - Installing ralouphie/getallheaders (3.0.3): Extracting archive

     - Installing psr/http-factory (1.0.1): Extracting archive

     - Installing guzzlehttp/psr7 (2.1.0): Extracting archive

     - Installing guzzlehttp/promises (1.5.1): Extracting archive

     - Installing guzzlehttp/guzzle (7.4.1): Extracting archive

     - Installing nikic/php-parser (v4.13.2): Extracting archive

     - Installing psy/psysh (v0.10.12): Extracting archive

     - Installing laravel/tinker (v2.6.3): Extracting archive

     - Installing sheetdb/sheetdb-php (1.0.3): Extracting archive

   Package swiftmailer/swiftmailer is abandoned, you should avoid using it. Use symfony/mailer instead.

   Generating optimized autoload files

   > Illuminate\Foundation\ComposerScripts::postAutoloadDump

   Deprecation Notice: Return type of Illuminate\Container\Container::offsetExists($key) should either be compatible with ArrayAccess::offsetExists(mixed $offset): bool, or the #[\ReturnTypeWillChange] attribute should be used to temporarily suppress the notice in /tmp/build_207a93aa/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/Container.php:1270

   Deprecation Notice: Return type of Illuminate\Container\Container::offsetGet($key) should either be compatible with ArrayAccess::offsetGet(mixed $offset): mixed, or the #[\ReturnTypeWillChange] attribute should be used to temporarily suppress the notice in /tmp/build_207a93aa/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/Container.php:1281

   Deprecation Notice: Return type of Illuminate\Container\Container::offsetSet($key, $value) should either be compatible with ArrayAccess::offsetSet(mixed $offset, mixed $value): void, or the #[\ReturnTypeWillChange] attribute should be used to temporarily suppress the notice in /tmp/build_207a93aa/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/Container.php:1293

   Deprecation Notice: Return type of Illuminate\Container\Container::offsetUnset($key) should either be compatible with ArrayAccess::offsetUnset(mixed $offset): void, or the #[\ReturnTypeWillChange] attribute should be used to temporarily suppress the notice in /tmp/build_207a93aa/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/Container.php:1306

   > @php artisan package:discover --ansi

   PHP Deprecated:  Return type of Illuminate\Container\Container::offsetExists($key) should either be compatible with ArrayAccess::offsetExists(mixed $offset): bool, or the #[\ReturnTypeWillChange] attribute should be used to temporarily suppress the notice in /tmp/build_207a93aa/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/Container.php on line 1270

   PHP Deprecated:  Return type of Illuminate\Container\Container::offsetGet($key) should either be compatible with ArrayAccess::offsetGet(mixed $offset): mixed, or the #[\ReturnTypeWillChange] attribute should be used to temporarily suppress the notice in /tmp/build_207a93aa/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/Container.php on line 1281

   PHP Deprecated:  Return type of Illuminate\Container\Container::offsetSet($key, $value) should either be compatible with ArrayAccess::offsetSet(mixed $offset, mixed $value): void, or the #[\ReturnTypeWillChange] attribute should be used to temporarily suppress the notice in /tmp/build_207a93aa/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/Container.php on line 1293

   PHP Deprecated:  Return type of Illuminate\Container\Container::offsetUnset($key) should either be compatible with ArrayAccess::offsetUnset(mixed $offset): void, or the #[\ReturnTypeWillChange] attribute should be used to temporarily suppress the notice in /tmp/build_207a93aa/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/Container.php on line 1306

   PHP Deprecated:  Return type of Illuminate\Config\Repository::offsetExists($key) should either be compatible with ArrayAccess::offsetExists(mixed $offset): bool, or the #[\ReturnTypeWillChange] attribute should be used to temporarily suppress the notice in /tmp/build_207a93aa/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Config/Repository.php on line 141

   PHP Deprecated:  Return type of Illuminate\Config\Repository::offsetGet($key) should either be compatible with ArrayAccess::offsetGet(mixed $offset): mixed, or the #[\ReturnTypeWillChange] attribute should be used to temporarily suppress the notice in /tmp/build_207a93aa/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Config/Repository.php on line 152

   PHP Deprecated:  Return type of Illuminate\Config\Repository::offsetSet($key, $value) should either be compatible with ArrayAccess::offsetSet(mixed $offset, mixed $value): void, or the #[\ReturnTypeWillChange] attribute should be used to temporarily suppress the notice in /tmp/build_207a93aa/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Config/Repository.php on line 164

   PHP Deprecated:  Return type of Illuminate\Config\Repository::offsetUnset($key) should either be compatible with ArrayAccess::offsetUnset(mixed $offset): void, or the #[\ReturnTypeWillChange] attribute should be used to temporarily suppress the notice in /tmp/build_207a93aa/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Config/Repository.php on line 175

   PHP Fatal error:  During inheritance of ArrayAccess: Uncaught ErrorException: Return type of Illuminate\Support\Collection::offsetExists($key) should either be compatible with ArrayAccess::offsetExists(mixed $offset): bool, or the #[\ReturnTypeWillChange] attribute should be used to temporarily suppress the notice in /tmp/build_207a93aa/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Support/Collection.php:1349

   Stack trace:

   #0 /tmp/build_207a93aa/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Support/Collection.php(11): Illuminate\Foundation\Bootstrap\HandleExceptions->handleError()

   #1 /tmp/build_207a93aa/vendor/composer/ClassLoader.php(571): include('...')

   #2 /tmp/build_207a93aa/vendor/composer/ClassLoader.php(428): Composer\Autoload\includeFile()

   #3 /tmp/build_207a93aa/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Support/helpers.php(110): Composer\Autoload\ClassLoader->loadClass()

   #4 /tmp/build_207a93aa/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/PackageManifest.php(130): collect()

   #5 /tmp/build_207a93aa/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/PackageManifest.php(106): Illuminate\Foundation\PackageManifest->build()

   #6 /tmp/build_207a93aa/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/PackageManifest.php(89): Illuminate\Foundation\PackageManifest->getManifest()

   #7 /tmp/build_207a93aa/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/PackageManifest.php(78): Illuminate\Foundation\PackageManifest->config()

   #8 /tmp/build_207a93aa/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Bootstrap/RegisterFacades.php(26): Illuminate\Foundation\PackageManifest->aliases()

   #9 /tmp/build_207a93aa/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Application.php(230): Illuminate\Foundation\Bootstrap\RegisterFacades->bootstrap()

   #10 /tmp/build_207a93aa/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Console/Kernel.php(310): Illuminate\Foundation\Application->bootstrapWith()

   #11 /tmp/build_207a93aa/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Console/Kernel.php(127): Illuminate\Foundation\Console\Kernel->bootstrap()

   #12 /tmp/build_207a93aa/artisan(37): Illuminate\Foundation\Console\Kernel->handle()

   #13 {main} in /tmp/build_207a93aa/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Support/Collection.php on line 11

   

   In Collection.php line 11:

                                                                                  

     During inheritance of ArrayAccess: Uncaught ErrorException: Return type of   

     Illuminate\Support\Collection::offsetExists($key) should either be compatib  

     le with ArrayAccess::offsetExists(mixed $offset): bool, or the #[\ReturnTyp  

     eWillChange] attribute should be used to temporarily suppress the notice in  

      /tmp/build_207a93aa/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Support/Collec  

     tion.php:1349                                                                

     Stack trace:                                                                 

     #0 /tmp/build_207a93aa/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Support/Coll  

     ection.php(11): Illuminate\Foundation\Bootstrap\HandleExceptions->handleErr  

     or()                                                                         

     #1 /tmp/build_207a93aa/vendor/composer/ClassLoader.php(571): include('...')  

     #2 /tmp/build_207a93aa/vendor/composer/ClassLoader.php(428): Composer\Autol  

     oad\includeFile()                                                            

     #3 /tmp/build_207a93aa/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Support/help  

     ers.php(110): Composer\Autoload\ClassLoader->loadClass()                     

     #4 /tmp/build_207a93aa/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/P  

     ackageManifest.php(130): collect()                                           

     #5 /tmp/build_207a93aa/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/P  

     ackageManifest.php(106): Illuminate\Foundation\PackageManifest->build()      

     #6 /tmp/build_207a93aa/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/P  

     ackageManifest.php(89): Illuminate\Foundation\PackageManifest->getManifest(  

     )                                                                            

     #7 /tmp/build_207a93aa/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/P  

     ackageManifest.php(78): Illuminate\Foundation\PackageManifest->config()      

     #8 /tmp/build_207a93aa/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/B  

     ootstrap/RegisterFacades.php(26): Illuminate\Foundation\PackageManifest->al  

     iases()                                                                      

     #9 /tmp/build_207a93aa/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/A  

     pplication.php(230): Illuminate\Foundation\Bootstrap\RegisterFacades->boots  

     trap()                                                                       

     #10 /tmp/build_207a93aa/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/  

     Console/Kernel.php(310): Illuminate\Foundation\Application->bootstrapWith()  

     #11 /tmp/build_207a93aa/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/  

     Console/Kernel.php(127): Illuminate\Foundation\Console\Kernel->bootstrap()   

     #12 /tmp/build_207a93aa/artisan(37): Illuminate\Foundation\Console\Kernel->  

     handle()                                                                     

     #13 {main}                                                                   

                                                                                  

   

   Script @php artisan package:discover --ansi handling the post-autoload-dump event returned with error code 255
```

!     WARNING: A post-autoload-dump script terminated with an error

!     ERROR: Dependency installation failed!

!

!     The 'composer install' process failed with an error. The cause

!     may be the download or installation of packages, or a pre- or

!     post-install hook (e.g. a 'post-install-cmd' item in 'scripts')

!     in your 'composer.json'.

!

!     Typical error cases are out-of-date or missing parts of code,

!     timeouts when making external connections, or memory limits.

!

!     Check the above error output closely to determine the cause of

!     the problem, ensure the code you're pushing is functioning

!     properly, and that all local changes are committed correctly.

!

!     For more information on builds for PHP on Heroku, refer to

!     https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/php-support

!

!     REMINDER: the following warnings were emitted during the build;

!     check the details above, as they may be related to this error:

!     - A post-autoload-dump script terminated with an error

!     Push rejected, failed to compile PHP app.

!     Push failed

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: i have the same problem, did you solve this issue ?

Comment: Yes I have solved the issue by changing PHP version in composer.json changed PHP version form 8.0 to 7.4,